# Drupal input required

Tags: input, drupal, required

The problem is clicking on "search" even when the search box is empty shows all the results.  But this should be shown input required

in Drupal view when I use the Exposed form

Exposed form in block:
Yes
Exposed form style:
Input required
In the exposed filter i also use the option "input required"
An error message appear.

Nothing was worked for me